# Subtracting floating point values in a list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, enumerate

I am trying to get it so my list starts at zero rather than the large number it originally starts at. To do this, I will have to subtract the initial value from all the other values in the list. The numbers in the list are floating-point and fairly large numbers. I need to somehow subtract the initial time from all other times. I have tried a few things which are here:

```
for index, time in enumerate(STARTTIME_MAX1):
    time = time/60
    #if time > 0:
    #    time = time - time[0]
    time = time - time[0]
    #time[:] = [time - time[0] for time in STARTTIME_MAX1]
    STARTTIME_MAX1[index] = time
```

I also tried this way:

```
for time in STARTTIME_MAX1:
    time = time/60
    time = time-time[0]
    print(time)
print(STARTTIME_MAX1)
```

and tried this:

```
STARTTIME_MIN = [((i/60)-i[0]) for i in STARTTIME_MAX1]
```

But every time I am getting an error: `TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable`.

I need to keep the values as floating-point so they are more exact. STARTTIME_MAX1 is just a list of measurement starting times, and I need to subtract the first starttime value from all the values in the list so that it starts at an initial time of zero and continues up from there.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you define STARTTIME_MAX1

Comment: I'm guessing STARTTIME_MAX1 is a list of numbers. So then what are you trying to do with `time[0]`?

Comment: You could use int(str(time)[0]) to perform the rest with the first number

Comment: `time` is a float because you assigned the result of a divide operation to it. So if it is a float, what do you intend by `time[0]`? It's hard to guess what you think it does.

Comment: I need to keep the values as floating-point so they are more exact. STARTTIME_MAX1 is just a list of measurement starting times, and I need to subtract the first starttime value from all the values in the list so that it starts at an initial time of zero and continues up from there.

Comment: For debugging help, you need to provide a [mre] including example input and desired output.

Comment: Python should convert ints to floats when doing arithmetic with an int and a float. I am sure that the error you get is caused by your calling variable time as an array or list. The only time you can call [i] is when the variable is either an array or string.

Comment: as @BoarGules asked, why are you calling time[0]? what are you trying to do? correct me if I'm wrong but I'm pretty sure the time[0] part should be STARTTIME_MAX1[0]

Comment: Oh wait a minute, you're just asking how to get the first value and subtract it from the list! I'll write an answer. But a [mre] would still help.

Comment: Yes exactly! But keeping it in floating-point values to preserve the accuracy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity, let's say you have a list like this:

```
a = [15, 16, 17, 19]
```

And you want to subtract the first value, 15:

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 4]
```

To get the first element, you can use `a[0]`, then you can subtract it from every element including itself. Here I'll use a comprehension with a full-slice-assignment.

```
initial = a[0]
a[:] = [x-initial for x in a]
# > a = [0, 1, 2, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

`time` is a float in your code, it's one of the elements in `STARTTIME_MAX1`.  Instead of using `time[0]` you probably want `STARTTIME_MAX1[0]`.

And please don't use `time` as a variable name, it might give you trouble later if you try to use `datetime.time`.

Comment: This won't work directly cause in the first snippet, `STARTTIME_MAX1[0]` will be modified by the first iteration. You'll need to capture it before the loop like `initial = STARTTIME_MAX1[0]; ...; STARTTIME_MAX1[index] = time - initial`. I wrote [an answer](/a/68338681/4518341) that does that.

Comment: @wjandrea you're right of course, silly of me to miss that.

Answer (score -1):

When you divide in python, you get a float output:
such in this line of your code and my example:

```
time = time/60

10/2
>> 5.0
```

To fix this you can A:

```
10//2
>> 5
```

`//` just returns the part before the decimal.
Or you can do B:

```
int(10/2)
>> 5
```

`int()` makes a float or a string form int into a integer

Comment: I need to somehow keep the time as a floating-point, so it is more exact. Is there a way to still do it but as a floating-point value rather than converting it to an int?

Comment: I think you missed the point of what OP's trying to do. If you have `time = 5`, then `time - time` will always be `0`. How does that help?

Comment: The start time starts at a very large value and increases from there. I want it to start with zero, so (time - the first value of time) will be 0, which is what I want, and from there on, will gradually increase since I will be doing larger time values minus the smaller initial time value.